# `^^I^^I^^I` on beginning of each line in minted

Tags: minted

I want to print some source code with minted, and the characters `^^I^^I^^I` appears on the beginning of each line. It is independent on the chosen language syntax.

It looks like so:

[image: output]

What can I do to get rid of it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How are you compiling? If you are using XeTeX you may need the `-8bit` option.

Comment: Well, yes, I'm using XeTeX, and with this option it works. Thank you!

Comment: @TeXnician, could you make it an answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm sure this is a duplicate, I'm going to answer this.

Your problem with `^^I` when compiling with XeLaTeX can be solved by using the command-line option `-8bit`.

Comment: Now I see why I haven't found it elsewhere. The ^^I is a tabulator, and my code was already indented a bit.

Comment: If you try https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22-8bit%22 the duplicate appears near the top.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the hint. I rarely use the site's search (mostly another search engine that does not output the result that fast).